# Typescript union type with singleton types does not compile

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why this does not compile:

```
type X = {
  id: "primary"
  inverted?: boolean
} | {
  id: "secondary"
  inverted?: boolean
} | {
  id: "tertiary"
  inverted?: false
}


const a = true
const x: X = {
  id: a ? "primary" : "secondary"
}
```

x should be a valid X in either case.

But the compiler complains:

```
test.ts:14:7 - error TS2322: Type '{ id: "primary" | "secondary"; }' is not assignable to type 'X'.
  Type '{ id: "primary" | "secondary"; }' is not assignable to type '{ id: "tertiary"; inverted?: false; }'.
    Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
      Type '"primary" | "secondary"' is not assignable to type '"tertiary"'.
        Type '"primary"' is not assignable to type '"tertiary"'.
```

Comment: Weird, especially code `type X = { id: "primary" | "secondary" | "tertiary" } & { inverted?: false };` works

Comment: Why not use a string literal type? `type Xid = "primary" | "secondary" | "tertiary"`

Comment: The example code is overly simplified. The actual type contains a lot more fields. The important part here is that in the tertiary type inverted must be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is working as intended https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29852#issuecomment-462461938

Answer (score 3):

It's a quirk of type checking. The ternary expression `a ? "primary" : "secondary"` will have the type `"primary" | "secondary"` this means the object literal is typed as `{ id : "primary" | "secondary" }`.

The way unions are checked is that for an object literal to be compatible with the union it must be compatible with at  least one member of the union. The problem is the object literal type above is compatible with neither of the union members so we end up with an error.

The simple way to fix is to move the check outside:

```
const x3: X = a ? { id: "primary" } : { id: "secondary" }
```

Or use a type assertion.

Comment: The example code is overly simplified. If I move the condition further out I would have to duplicate some code.

Comment: @Bomgar I thought taht might be the case. Unfortunately the only other option is a type assertion or an `Object.assign(a ? { id: "primary" as "primary" } : { id: "secondary" as "secondary"  }, {
  
})`